# TYPO3 BE Refresh Login method

Tags: php, authentication, typo3, typo3-8.x

I have created my own simple plugin, that authenticates backend users with my remote server:

```
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addService($_EXTKEY, 'auth', \My\Hooks\MyAuthService::class, [
    'title' => 'MY-Authentication',
    'description' => 'My Authentication service (FE and BE).',
    'subtype' => 'getUserBE,authUserBE',
    'available' => 1,
    'priority' => 60,
    'quality' => 60,
    'os' => '',
    'exec' => '',
    'className' => \My\Hooks\MyAuthService::class
]);
```

But I didn't know that TYPO3 has a "Refresh Login" screen option:

[image]

I noticed, that on submit, it calls:

```
/typo3/index.php?ajaxID=/ajax/rsa/publickey&skipSessionUpdate=1
```

But what Service/Method does this ajax call?

Does it use the same authentication service I have already defined? If so, what is the specific method it uses?

A link to the correct manual will suffice also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the exact position of this script, but found the corresponding JavaScript file. Maybe this helps: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_8-7/typo3/sysext/backend/Resources/Public/JavaScript/LoginRefresh.js

But I'm pretty sure that it uses all registered login services.